# Net short term capital gain in India

Tags: india, capital-gains-tax

Suppose I have two securities A and B in India. I sell A at a profit of 100 INR, and B at a loss of 90 INR. Both transactions are short-term. So my net gain is 10 INR. But I buy B immediately afterwards. Am I still allowed to show my net gain as 10 INR?

Comment: @nanoman Rules in India keep changing. That's a 2016 answer. I just wanted to be certain that things have not changed. Also, I don't know what "derecognition" in that answer  means.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can.  However ensure you buy stock B the next day... else some brokers show buying and selling same day as day trading and the tax treatment is different.